# Using a metaclass on an Enum type, and making Pylint happy with it

Tags: python, enums, pylint

I have the following `Enum` subclass; the class itself is needed so `__str__` returns the string representation of the value (not the fully qualified name), and the metaclass is there to ensure i’m using unique values.

```py
from enum import Enum


class StringifiedEnumMeta(type(Enum)):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        assert len(set(self.__members__.keys())) == len(set(self.__members__.values()))


class StringifiedEnum(Enum, metaclass=StringifiedEnumMeta):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

This *seems* to work as expected; for example, the following code fails with an `AssertionError`:

```py
class MyEnum(StringifiedEnum):
    KEY1 = 'value'
    KEY2 = 'value'
```

However, PyLint reports i’m using an invalid metaclass:

```
mwe.py:8:0: E1139: Invalid metaclass 'StringifiedEnumMeta' used (invalid-metaclass)
```

Is this really an invalid metaclass, or is PyLint at mistake here?

Comment: Shouldn't `StringifiedEnum` use `StringifiedEnumMeta` for its metaclass? (Appears to be a typo in the question.)

Comment: `enum` already exports `EnumMeta`; no need for `type(Enum)`.

Comment: Yeah, it’s a typo in my example… fixing that in a moment.

Comment: If the code works, it's certainly a PyLint issue. If it were really an invalid metaclass, then the code *wouldn't* work.

Comment: Why don't you use the `enum.unique` decorator?  It's purpose in life is to make sure each value is only used once, no metaclass needed.